# How to pull the data from a table with columns which allow nulls to the table of not null-able columns

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

i need to pull the data from table which has all columns of allowing null type to another table which have columns matching with previous table but of not null type.

So i need a query for pulling entire data of all the matching columns.with a default value in the position of null row.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? tag it

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that a given column is of integer type and default value is 0. You can use below based on your RDBMS:

**SQL Server**

```
ISNULL(COL_1,0)
```

**Oracle**

```
NVL(COL_1,0)

or

COALESCE(COL_1,0)
```

**MYSQL**

```
IFNULL(COL_1,0)

or

COALESCE(COL_1,0)
```

Replace the col_1 with your column name and default value 0 with appropriate value